# Importing Variables Containing Commas from CSV Files

Tags: r, csv, format, numeric

My data is a CSV file from Microsoft Excel. This file contains several numeric variables (e.g. salary, weight) that are written in the following format: 123,456 (one hundred and twenty three thousand four hundred and fifty six).

When I import this file ("old_file") into R using the following command : `my_file = read.csv("old_file.csv")`, all the numeric variables are automatically converted to factor variable types.

To solve this problem, I tried to manually convert these variables into numeric variable types after importing the file into R:

```
my_file$var_1 = as.numeric(my_file$var_1)
```

However, doing this seems to "distort" the data. For example, values of "var_1" that are naturally occurring 0's seem to disappear. I also plotted some histograms of this data and the distribution of these numeric converted variables do not match the expected distributions.

I was able to solve this problem by opening the Excel Spreadsheet and clicking the "format button" and removing the "commas" from the numeric variables, and adding ".00" to the end of each number. For example, 123,456 now becomes 123456.00 .

[image]

Once I made this change in the original Excel Spreadsheet, the problem was then resolved.

**My Question:** Is there a way to solve this problem in R, instead of manually doing this in the original Excel Spreadsheet? I just happened to catch this formatting error - in the future, is there a way to automatically prevent this from happening in R? E.g. Some way to ensure that variables that "appear to be numeric in the Excel File" get imported as numeric types in R?

Comment: @ BigBen: Thank you for your reply! I did not know this! I will keep this in mind - thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I believe this problem can be solved by saving the excel file as a csv (which should insert quotation marks around the numbers) and then reading the file in using the `read_csv()` function from the [readr package](https://readr.tidyverse.org/), e.g.

Test data:

```
Value1,Value2
"123,456","456,678"
"234,567","445,678,899"
```

```
library(readr)
read_csv("~/Desktop/test.csv")
#> Rows: 2 Columns: 2
#> Warning in min(width - (crayon::col_nchar(types) + nchar(counts) + 4)): no non-
#> missing arguments to min; returning Inf
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   Value1    Value2
#>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 123456    456678
#> 2 234567 445678899
```

The numbers are now numeric (double precision integers).

Compared with the read.csv() function:

```
read.csv("~/Desktop/test.csv")
#>    Value1      Value2
#> 1 123,456     456,678
#> 2 234,567 445,678,899
```

(The numbers are not in the correct format)

Comment: @j ared_mamrot: thank you for your reply! my excel file was originally saved as a CSV - if I run your code, is there any way to import these numbers as "numeric" instead of "integers"? thank you!

Comment: I believe this code does what you want: if you use `df <- read_csv("file.csv")` then `str(df)` the class of the imported numbers is "numeric". See e.g. https://faculty.nps.edu/sebuttre/home/R/data.html for more details on the different classes in R